# Jquery cycle pager with menu tree?

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation

I have gotten lots of help from others posts in the past so I hope you can help me out now.

I want to use the jquery cycle with a pager function (http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager3.html)
but instead of it generating thumbnails as links I would like the navigation to be text links in an accordion tree like this lovely demo: jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/?1.0

My main issue is that the pager cycle generated numbers instead of text as links, and to override that I tried using the 'title' tag in the image tag, and change the 'return' in the js

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#s4').before('<div id="nav" class="nav">').cycle({ 
          fx:     'fade',
          speed:  'fast',
          timeout: 0,
          pager:  '#nav',
           pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
          return '<li>' + $(slide).attr('title') +  '</li>';

            } 
            });
        });
  </script>
```

which worked-- -but then gives me no ability to manipulate or style the text links.
And I would ideally like to have the nav in a text tree like the link above.

I am quite new to JQuery and have learned what I know only from going through threads, tuts and forums but am not really able to figure out how to write it correctly on my own...so frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

The cycle documentation recommends you use css, such as

```
#nav a { border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #fc0; text-decoration: none; margin: 0 5px; padding: 3px 5px; }
#nav a.activeSlide { background: #ea0 }
#nav a:focus { outline: none; }
```

If you didn't want all that in your pristine css files, you could write it into your html with $('head').append() or something. Or you could style the elements with jQuery using something like

```
$('#nav a').css({
  border: '1px solid #ccc',
  background: '#fc0',
  text-decoration: 'none',
  margin: '0 5px',
  padding: '3px 5px',
  focus: { outline: 'none' }
}).filter('.activeSlide').css({
  background: '#ea0'
});
```

That's untested, and the "focus: {...}" part is just wishful thinking. I don't know if there's a way to do that with jQuery.